# How does one prove that $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad a^{13} = a \bmod 35$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

How does one prove that $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z},  \quad a^{13} = a \bmod 35$?

---

I would recall that $a^p = a \bmod p$ if $p$ does not divide $a$, but $13 \neq 35$ and besides the statement should hold for any integer $a$. It looks like there is some relationship between $13$ and $35$ that I don't see. A hint would be nice.

Comment: First of all, $a^p \equiv a \mod p$ holds if $p$ is prime for *all* integers $a$. Secondly, notice that $35$ is not prime. What theorem might be handy to break down this congruence?

Comment: Note that if $a$ is divisible by $5$ then $a^{13}\equiv a \pmod{5}$. Also, if $a$ is not divisible by $5$, then $a^4\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, so $a^{12}\equiv 1$, so $a^{13}\equiv a\pmod{5}$. Now do something similar for $7$, and combine the two results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ By little Fermat, $\ {\rm mod}\ 7\!:\ \color{#0a0}{a^7}\equiv \color{#c00}a\,\Rightarrow\, a^{13} = \color{#0a0}{a^7} a^6\equiv\, \color{#c00}{a}\, a^6\equiv\color{#0a0}{ a^7}\equiv \color{#c00}a $

Similarly  $\,a^{13}\equiv a\pmod 5,\ $ so $\ 5,7\mid a^{13}\!-a\,\Rightarrow\, 35\mid a^{13}\!-a,\,$ by $\,{\rm lcm}(5,7) = 35$

Answer (score 1):

For all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ hold:
$$a^4 \equiv 1 \mod 5$$
$$a^6 \equiv 1 \mod 7$$
Hence
$$a^{12} \equiv 1^3 \equiv 1 \mod 5$$
$$a^{12} \equiv 1^2 \equiv 1 \mod 7$$
so by the Chinese Remainder Theorem
$$a^{12} \equiv 1 \mod 35$$
and multiplying by $a$
$$a^{13} \equiv a \mod 35$$

Comment: This is certainly incorrect as is. In the first 4 congruences, the 1's need to be replaced with "1 or 0". Then some work needs to be done in the various cases.